# How to go from one exception handler to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

The best way to explain my question is with the following pseudo-code:

```
try
{
    //Do work
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == -2)
    {
        debugLogSQLTimeout(ex);
    }
    else
    {
        //How to go to 'Exception' handler?
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    debugLogGeneralException(ex);
}
```

Comment: why dont' you just debugLogGeneralException(ex); in place of your comment?

Comment: @romanm: As I said it's just a pseudo-code and that is not a real function in my actual example.

Comment: all i'm saying is you should put your "Exception handler" logic in place of your comment, instead of "going" there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Exception ex = null;
try
{
    //Do work
}
catch (SqlException sqlEx)
{
    ex = sqlEx;
    if (ex.Number == -2)
    {
       //..
    }
    else
    {
        //..
    }
}
catch (Exception generalEx)
{
  ex = generalEx;
}
finally()
{
  if (ex != null) debugLogGeneralException(ex);
}
```

Comment: Very nice. I was hoping for some `rethrow` command, but this will also work.

Answer (score 1):

The first `catch` clause that matches is the only one that can possibly run on the same `try` block.

The best way I can think of to do what you're attempting is to include casts and conditionals in the more general type:

```
try
{
    //Do work
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var sqlEx = ex as SqlException;
    if (sqlEx != null && sqlEx.Number == -2)
    {
        debugLogSQLTimeout(ex);
    }
    else
    {
        debugLogGeneralException(ex);
    }
}
```

If you find yourself writing this over and over again throughout your data layer, at least take the time to encapsulate it in a method.

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know that one can cast an exception like that. It won't raise an exception of it's own, will it? (Say, if it's an arithmetic overflow exception.)

Comment: In this case, given that we're comparing sqlEx.Number to a constant value (which I probably would have declared a `const` for in production code), I don't think there's a real risk of popping an unhandled exception.

Comment: Hmm... NOW I understand your question... I think. And no, the process of `as`-casting an exception to another type will NOT somehow trigger the re-raising of that exception. You would have to `throw()` it for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is any way to do this as the catch blocks are in different scopes. There's no way to re-throw without exiting the try block and no way to 'call' the final catch block because it's only triggered during an exception.

I would suggest the same as roman m above and just make the same call. Otherwise you have to do something really bad. Like the below crazy code which you should never ever use but i included because it does something like what you want.

In general I think what you are doing is controlling normal flow via exceptions which isn't recommended. If you are trying to track for timeouts, you should probably just handle that another way.

Note that you could do something like the code below with the insanity of a goto statement, but i included it so no one can forget what a bad idea this is. =)

```
void Main()
{
    Madness(new NotImplementedException("1")); //our 'special' case we handle
    Madness(new NotImplementedException("2")); //our 'special' case we don't handle
    Madness(new Exception("2")); //some other error
}

void Madness(Exception e){
    Exception myGlobalError;

    try
    {
        throw e;
    }
    catch (NotImplementedException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message.Equals("1"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("handle special error");
        }
        else
        {
            myGlobalError = ex;
            Console.WriteLine("going to our crazy handler");
            goto badidea;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        myGlobalError = ex;
        Console.WriteLine("going to our crazy handler");
        goto badidea;
    }
    return;

    badidea:
    try{
        throw myGlobalError;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is crazy!");
    }
}
// Define other methods and classes here
```

Comment: =) I was hoping to make sure it was crazy enough no one would actually use it. I agree with roman m's comment on the original code. No matter what you do, you'll still be doing something this crazy really. Even the try/catch/finally will cause you to have null check regardless of error on every single operation that calls the try/catch/finally. probably not a lot of overhead, but it is something. none of the answers given actually 'go to' the other exception handler because you can't.